# IE 6 and 7 being detected as Mobile devices

Tags: spring-mvc, wurfl

We are using **wurfl-device-resolver** to handle mobile devices that access our application and everything is working as a charm. However Internet Explorer is being detected as a mobile device. We already added the official web browser xml patch that is supposed to solve this but with no results. This is how the device resolver configuration looks like:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="deviceResolver" class="org.springframework.mobile.device.mvc.DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor">
        <constructor-arg>
            <device:wurfl-device-resolver root-location="/WEB-INF/wurfl/wurfl.zip" patch-locations="/WEB-INF/wurfl/web_browsers_patch.xml"/>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Those sniffers usually work off the UserAgent string - have you looked at the raw agent strings on the IE6/7 browsers getting caught in this? Since every plugin under the sun seems to need to advertise their presence in there, possibly one of them is triggering the false positive.

Comment: They do work using User agent and in fact the User Agent is exactly the same than one used for a HTC Phone with Windows Mobile, which causes the false positive. However the web_browsers_patch.xml is supposed to fix that by giving priority to the web browser detection over the mobile devices. So that should fix IE6/7 but break the HTC Phone (which we don't care). The issue here is that its not working.

Comment: Try to post this answer to the wmlprogramming mailing list. Luca Passani the inventor of wurfl can help you.